# Create a new object using an existing id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use SQLAlchemy to define a `User` class.

if an user is not logged on my website, I want to identify him as an `AnonymousUser`. I want my `AnonymousUser` to be a subclass of my normal `User` class, with special method (eg. `is_anonymous(self): return true`).

Now, there is an anonymous user that I created initially in my database, with (say) `id = 0`.

I would like to define `AnonymousUser` as a subclass of `User`, where the constructor only returns the anonymous user :

```
class AnonymousUser(User):
    def __init__(self):
        anonymous_user = User.get_by_id(0)
        self.username = anonymous_user.username
        self.id = anonymous_user.id
        ...
```

but when I create an `AnonymousUser`, it does not understand that I don't want a new `User`, but only to create an existing `User`, and it commits the creation of a new `User` to the session, and since the `id` has been set to the existing anonymous_user `id` it crashes because of the id unicity condition

How can I tell SQLAlchemy to create a `User` object using an existing id?

Is there a more elegant way to do what I want?

I know that I could simply define an anonymous_user by using `User.get_by_id(0)`, but then I would have to add an `is_anonymous` field to my object and have a variable check each time I check whether my user is anonymous (rather than having two distinct classes, one with a trivial implementation `is_anonymous: return False` and the other using `is_anonymous: return True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick suggestion. You can implement your is_anonymous method on the User class like this:

```
def is_anonymous(self):
    return self.id == 0
```